# Update Enum By API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, orm

I want to update Enum value runtime.I am using JPAand Currently have a Enum as

```
public enum ColorEnum
{
    A, B, C
}
```

And Using this Enum in Entity As:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "Color_Enum ", nullable = false)
private ColorEnum colorEnum ;
```

its working for But I want to provide a api to add new Enum 'D' in future if there is requirement. In that case what is the best approach to create entity and is there any way to alter enum?

Comment: I would rather suggest using a referential table for such requirements

Comment: Lets drop the enum type color. It can be anything I just want to add new Enum by provideing a API to end user (admin )so in future they can add new enum type. and i am looking for solution at database end and JPA entity side. How I should add Column in Entity in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The way to accomplish this is to use an interface.

```
interface Colour
{
    String getHex(); // or whatever a colour does 
}
```

You can then declare default colours:

```
enum DefaultColour implements Colour
{
    RED("ff0000"),
    BLUE("0000ff");

    private final String hex;

    DefaultColour(String hex) { this.hex = hex; }

    @Override
    public String getHex() { return hex; }
}
```

Then when someone wants to add an additional colour, they can implement the same interface:

```
class Gold implements Colour {
    //...
}
```

or provide a whole list:

```
enum AdditionalColour implements Colour {
    YELLOW("..."),
    GREEN("...");

    //...
}
```

I'd use a [service provider interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) to provide the extra colours at runtime.

Comment: Lets drop the enum type color. It can be anything I just want to add new Enum by provideing a API to end user (admin )so in future they can add new enum type. and i am looking for solution at database end and JPA entity side. How I should add Column in Entity in this case

Comment: I don't understand the question. `Enum` should be used for a finite set. If the set is unbounded, just use `class Colour { }` which stores a string (or whatever) and store a `Set<Colour>` somewhere.

Comment: Actually I Have a Column "device" in table which can store fixed value (a,b,c). but now I want to give privilege to the admin so they can add new value like "D"  in column definition so Everyone can also add the new device. so now I am ready to change the the code where I used the Enums.  I know that I can use a New Table to store the device type and validate the device type when other member inserting the device. So I am looking for Best approach with JPA.

Answer (score 1):

> Enums are intended to be static, final, immutable, instance-controlled objects that have the sense of constants [...]

I would either recommend to use a `String` or a serializable class that represents your color (like RBG values) and persist that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "color")
public class ColorEntity implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "red", nullable = false)
    private int red;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "green", nullable = false)
    private int green;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "blue", nullable = false)
    private int blue;

    // remainder omitted
}
```